# Change/clear form value on validation error

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm creating a html page with a form containing only one field: `cardId`. The user needs to fill in this field with a card reader (keyboard like input). When `cardId` validation fails, the user may try again (e.g. an incomplete read). Naturally, this is only possible if the previous input is cleared.

I'm using the following dependencies in my gradle build

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
```

Two RequestMappings:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String cardSearch(CardSearch cardSearch) {
    return "search";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String cardResult(@Valid CardSearch cardSearch, BindingResult result, Model model) {

    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        return "search";
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Form object

```
public class CardSearch {
    @CustomValidator(message = "Card not found...")
    private String cardId;

    Getter and setter
}
```

I'm using a custom validator to validate the `cardId`

```
@Override
public boolean isValid(String cardField, ConstraintValidatorContext cxt) {
    Card card = find card by cardField;

    if(card == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Form

```
<div th:errors="${cardSearch.cardId}"></div>
<form action="#" th:action="@{search}" th:object="${cardSearch}" method="post">
   <input type="text" th:field="*{cardId}" autofocus="autofocus" size="50" showPassword="true" />
</form>
```

When validation fails, the error message is shown to the user, but the fautly cardId is in the input field. One possible solution is to use a password input field (the browsers clears the input), but then the input is masked. What better way to clear the `cardId`?

[Edit] added github example https://github.com/JohanBas/FormReset

Comment: Clearing the form object should take care of that if that doesn't work, clear the value from the `BindingResult`.

Comment: Clearing the form object also clears the error message. How can i clear the value from the `BindingResult`?

Comment: Setting the value to an empty value should do that. What have you tried?

Comment: There is no setter in `BindingResult` [BindingResult API](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/BindingResult.html). You can do `getModel()` but changing values in the model didn't work. I also tried the `PropertyEditor` but no success.

Comment: Still what have you tried? I was hinting on doing simply `cardSearch.setCardId(null)` before returning the view. I suspect you did something else...

Comment: I've tried a lot of different things, hence the question on what to do. `cardSearch.setCardId(null)` does not reset the form field.

Comment: You only have `@Valid` on the argument used as the model, add `@ModelAttribute` on both your methods.

Comment: Good suggestion, but no luck. I've created a small spring-boot app to illustrate my problem: https://github.com/JohanBas/FormReset

Comment: Please show your form.

Comment: Form added. You can find a minimal project illustrating the problem on github. Just clone it, run it en try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT : add precisions on :

- not loosing error messages
- Thymeleaf problem

You have to reset the `cardId` in the model, and the attribute name must match what you use in your form (and that you didn't say ...)

You can do it explicitely :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String cardResult(@Valid CardSearch cardSearch, BindingResult result, Model model) {

    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute("how_you_call_it_in_your_form", new CardSearch());
        return "search";
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

But as you have changed the object, `result` not longer points to a model attribute and will not be used for displaying eventual errors. It is better to have spring do it automatically :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String cardResult(@Valid @ModelAttribute("how_you_call_it_in_your_form") CardSearch cardSearch,
        BindingResult result, Model model) {

    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        carSearch.setId(null);
        return "search";
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

**But Thymeleaf was there** : There is one sentence in Thymeleaf doc that intrigued me : *Values for th:field attributes must be selection expressions ( *{...} ), which makes sense given the fact that they will be evaluated on the form-backing bean and not on the context variables (or model attributes in Spring MVC jargon).*

What that means is that Thymeleaf will simply ignore all modifications to the bean that can occur in the controller !

If you want to make it work, you **must not use `th:field`** but the less magical `th:value` in your form

```
<input type="text" name="field" th:value="${formObject.field}" autofocus="autofocus" size="50" />
```

It is far less Thymeleaf-styled but at least it works

I admit I am not a Thymeleaf expert, and maybe there are cleaner ways to achieve this ...

Comment: `model.addAttribute("how_you_call_it_in_your_form", new CardSearch());` clears the form input but also clears the error message. This way, the user does not know something went wrong. `carSearch.setId(null);` with the correct `@ModelAttribute` does not clear the input field.

Comment: You are right. Great catch, i never thought Thymeleaf was to blame and i wasn't looking in that direction. Thanks for the effort and explanation!

Answer (score 5):

Actually I had a similar problem but the other way around. I wanted my value to NOT be deleted if an error occured. I am also using **th:field** and it works for me now.

I needed to manually add field errors with **new FieldError** even after using @Valid.

So if you do this, the value of the field **DOES NOT** get cleared:

```
bindingResult.addError(
   new FieldError("formObject", "field", formObject.getField(), true, null, null, 
                  messageSource.getMessage("you.fail", null , Locale.getDefault())));
```

And if you do this, the value of the field **will get** cleared:

```
bindingResult.addError(new FieldError("formObject", "field", 
                  messageSource.getMessage("you.fail", null , Locale.getDefault())));
```

See the constructors of **FieldError** especially the one with **rejectedValue**:

```
 /**
 * Create a new FieldError instance.
 * @param objectName the name of the affected object
 * @param field the affected field of the object
 * @param rejectedValue the rejected field value
 * @param bindingFailure whether this error represents a binding failure
 * (like a type mismatch); else, it is a validation failure
 * @param codes the codes to be used to resolve this message
 * @param arguments the array of arguments to be used to resolve this message
 * @param defaultMessage the default message to be used to resolve this message
 */
public FieldError(
        String objectName, String field, Object rejectedValue, boolean bindingFailure,
        String[] codes, Object[] arguments, String defaultMessage) {
```

Comment: I had the same problem where <input th:field="*{field}"/> will not show the value if you use the second one. new FieldError(objectName, field, defaultMessage), but <span th:text="*{field}"> will show the value!